# using git switched to other branch and master no longer listed in branches

Tags: git, aptana

I just installed aptana in cfbuilder 2.0.1.   Connected to our existing git repository on github and everything looked great.  All existing branches were on the list.  I switched to an different branch off master and everything still looked fine.

When I went to switch back to master, it was not in the list of branches.  I ended up switching at the command prompt.  Still no master branch in cfbuilder.  I restarted cfbuilder and it now said I was on the master branch.

So this does not seem like normal git operations.   Am I missing something?

Thanks

Tim

Comment: Which version of EGit do you have installed on you CFBuilder2?

Comment: I use the git provided for osx by github.com  git version 1.7.5.4

Comment: Yes, but CFBuilder2 is using that git with the Egit Eclipse plugin, and it would help if you can add its version to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Also - are you sure that no other committer has accidentally deleted the master branch itself? There is, afaik, nothing in git that says that there will always be a master branch - you can create a git repo where the default branch is called "xyz" for eg.